# Stop order won't trigger Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am debugging my pine script, and so I put labels on each candle to track target and stop ticks but for some reason the stoploss just won't trigger

The number on top is target ticks and that on bottom is stop loss ticks
[image]

```
float targetLTick = na
float stopLTick = na

if(longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long Buy",true,1,comment ="Long Buy \n" + "Target is " + tostring(targetLR) + "\n" + "StopLoss is " + tostring(stopLR))
    //label.new(bar_index,high,,color = color.white)
    
if(longCondition and strategy.position_size == 0)
    //average_long    = close
    targetLTick     := (targetLR - close) / syminfo.mintick
    stopLTick       := (close - stopLR) / syminfo.mintick
    
    label.new(x= bar_index,y= high, text = "Target ticks = " + tostring(targetLTick) +"\n"+" Stoploss ticks = " + tostring(stopLTick),textcolor = color.white)

if(strategy.position_size > 0)
    targetLTick := targetLTick[1]
    stopLTick   := stopLTick[1]
    label.new(x= bar_index,y= high, text =tostring(targetLTick) +"\n"+ tostring(stopLTick),textcolor = color.white)

strategy.exit("Long Buy",   profit = targetLTick,   comment = "Take Profit")
strategy.exit("Long Buy",   stop = stopLTick,       comment = "Book Loss")

strategy.close_all(when = closing_Bell,comment = "Closing Bell")
```

Comment: Did you try with the `backtest_fill_limits_assumption=0` parameter in `strategy()`?

Comment: No, but isn't "backtest_fill_limits_assumption=0", a default value. Also, I got my stoploss to work by using using 'stop' parameter instead of 'loss' parameter (don't know why it worked this way and not the other way) but still having problems with the target. This is baffling me, stoploss triggers perfectly now but targets get crossed above and below but the strategy won't close..